# Angularjs json array nested object download to csv

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After downloading into csv, i am getting this result, where the display setting is displaying [object Object]

[image]

How it should look like

[image]

My JS :

```
  $scope.download = function () {
  var csv = jsonToCsv(['ThemeName', 'DataSharing', 
 'DisplaySetting', 'ExpiryDate', 'Icon', 
 'PusblishDate','QueryName','ThemeName', 'ThemeOwner'], health)
  var csvBlob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
  saveAs(csvBlob, 'json.csv');
  };
```

May i ask how to modify the code so that it would show? And also is it possible to choose what object I want to display in the csv file? 
I would really really appreciate any help! I don't mind changing to another way of coding as long as it has the solution. So, if you have any link which I can refer to would be really nice too. Thanks!

Stringify

```
   else if ($scope.all[i].CATEGORY == 'Health')
  {
     health.DISPLAY_SETTING = 
     JSON.stringify(health.DISPLAY_SETTING)
     health.push($scope.all[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try stringifying the `DisplaySetting` property inside `health` before converting it to csv:

```
health.DisplaySetting = JSON.stringify(health.DisplaySetting);
```

Comment: I updated my code above, is that how you do it? Cause it's not working for me